# Getting “OutOfMemory Error in GpuMemory: 0” from small CNN and small data-set

Tags: out-of-memory, gpu, tensorflow2.0, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson-nano

My objective is to train a very simple CNN on MNIST using Tensorflow, convert it to TensorRT, and use it to perform inference on the MNIST test set using TensorRT, all on a Jetson Nano, but I am getting several errors and warnings, including “OutOfMemory Error in GpuMemory: 0”. To try and reduce memory footprint, I tried also creating a script where I simply load the TensorRT model (that had already been converted and saved in the previous script) and use it to perform inference on a small subset of the MNIST test set (100 floating point values), but I am still getting the same out of memory error. The entire directory containing the TensorRT model is only 488 KB, and the 100 test points can’t be taking up very much memory, so I am confused about why GPU memory is running out. What could be the reason for this, and how can I solve it?

Another thing which seems suspicious is that some of the Tensorflow logging info messages are being printed multiple times, EG “Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart”, “Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas”, “ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero”. What could be the reason for this (EG dynamic libraries being opened over and over again), and could this have something to do with why the GPU memory keeps running out?

Shown below are the 2 Python scripts; the console output from each one is too long to post on Stack Overflow, but they can be seen attached to this Gist: https://gist.github.com/jakelevi1996/8a86f2c2257001afc939343891ee5de7

```py
"""
Example script which trains a simple CNN for 1 epoch on a subset of MNIST, and
converts the model to TensorRT format, for enhanced performance which fully
utilises the NVIDIA GPU, and then performs inference.

Useful resources:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846828/how-to-convert-tensorflow-2-0-savedmodel-to-tensorrt
- https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#worflow-with-savedmodel
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/tensorrt/Converter
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34339
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/master/tftrt/examples/image-classification/image_classification.py

Tested on the NVIDIA Jetson Nano, Python 3.6.9, tensorflow 2.1.0+nv20.4, numpy
1.16.1
"""
import os
from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np

t0 = perf_counter()

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models, Input
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() # see github issue above

# Get training and test data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1) / 255.0
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1) / 255.0

# Create model
model = models.Sequential()
# model.add(Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:], batch_size=batch_size))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(10, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

# Compile and train model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    x_train[:10000], y_train[:10000], validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    batch_size=100, epochs=1,
)

# Save model
print("Saving model...")
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
model_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "CNN_MNIST")
if not os.path.isdir(model_dir): os.makedirs(model_dir)
# model.save(model_dir)
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_dir)


# Convert to TRT format
trt_model_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "CNN_MNIST_TRT")
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(input_saved_model_dir=model_dir)
converter.convert()
converter.save(trt_model_dir)

t1 = perf_counter()
print("Finished TRT conversion; time taken = {:.3f} s".format(t1 - t0))


# Make predictions using saved model, and print the results (NB using an alias
# for tf.saved_model.load, because the normal way of calling this function
# throws an error because for some reason it is expecting a sess)
saved_model_loaded = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load_v2(
    export_dir=trt_model_dir, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures[
    signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
graph_func = convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(graph_func)
x_test_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test, dtype=tf.float32)
preds = graph_func(x_test_tensor)[0].numpy()
print(preds.shape, y_test.shape)
accuracy = list(preds.argmax(axis=1) == y_test).count(True) / y_test.size
print("Accuracy of predictions = {:.2f} %".format(accuracy * 100))
```

```py
"""
Example script which trains a simple CNN for 1 epoch on a subset of MNIST, and
converts the model to TensorRT format, for enhanced performance which fully
utilises the NVIDIA GPU.

Useful resources:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846828/how-to-convert-tensorflow-2-0-savedmodel-to-tensorrt
- https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#worflow-with-savedmodel
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/tensorrt/Converter
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34339
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/master/tftrt/examples/image-classification/image_classification.py

Tested on the NVIDIA Jetson Nano, Python 3.6.9, tensorflow 2.1.0+nv20.4, numpy
1.16.1
"""
import os
from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np

t0 = perf_counter()

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() # see github issue above

# Get training and test data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1) / 255.0
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1) / 255.0

# TEMPORARY: just use 100 test points to minimise GPU memory
num_points = 100
x_test, y_test = x_test[:num_points], y_test[:num_points]

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
trt_model_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "CNN_MNIST_TRT")
# Make predictions using saved model, and print the results (NB using an alias
# for tf.saved_model.load, because the normal way of calling this function
# throws an error because for some reason it is expecting a sess)
saved_model_loaded = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load_v2(
    export_dir=trt_model_dir, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures[
    signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
graph_func = convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(graph_func)
x_test_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test, dtype=tf.float32)
preds = graph_func(x_test_tensor)[0].numpy()
print(preds.shape, y_test.shape)
accuracy = list(preds.argmax(axis=1) == y_test).count(True) / y_test.size
print("Accuracy of predictions = {:.2f} %".format(accuracy * 100))

t1 = perf_counter()
print("Finished inference; time taken = {:.3f} s".format(t1 - t0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error on a Jetson Tx2. I think it comes from the shared memory between the GPU and the CPU, tensorflow doesn't allow enough memory or the os limit the allocation.

To fix this, you can allow memory growth:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Or you can force tensorflow to allocate enough memory:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=2048)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Those example comes from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

Comment: Thank you Thlang! The first suggestion did not make the errors go away, but your second suggestion (to set `tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration`) worked, and now I am not getting the `OutOfMemory Error in GpuMemory: 0` error, or the other errors, or the quite ridiculous logs of all those memory addresses that are free or in use. I still am getting the info messages that the dynamic libraries are being opened repeatedly, but I'll look into this separately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see in logs that it created GPU device with 600 Mb:

```
Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 638 MB memory)
```

And then it tried to allocate 1Gb:

```
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.00GiB (rounded to 1073742336).
```

Also it's clear. that GPU device has more memory than 600Mb. It's visible here in the logs:

```
2020-06-23 23:06:36.463934: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0 name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 computeCapability: 5.3
coreClock: 0.9216GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 3.87GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 194.55MiB/s
```

So maybe your GPU is running some other calculation?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the GPU shouldn't have been running any other calculations (I'm the only one using it and I hadn't set off any other calculations to run in the background since booting it up)... but these are useful observations, so thank you!